# How to store facebook authenticated user in DB?

Tags: spring, facebook, spring-boot, spring-oauth2

I tried to implement this tutorial https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/#_social_login_logout
This is my application config(spring boot)

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"org.fiodorov.controller","org.fiodorov.service", "org.fiodorov.config"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = "org.fiodorov.model")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "org.fiodorov.repository")
@EnableOAuth2Client
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/**")
        .addFilterBefore(ssoFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(
                Application.class, args);
    }

    private Filter ssoFilter() {
        OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter facebookFilter = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter("/login/facebook");
        OAuth2RestTemplate facebookTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(facebook(), oauth2ClientContext);
        facebookFilter.setRestTemplate(facebookTemplate);
        facebookFilter.setTokenServices(new UserInfoTokenServices(facebookResource().getUserInfoUri(), facebook().getClientId()));
        return facebookFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("facebook.client")
    OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails facebook() {
        return new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("facebook.resource")
    ResourceServerProperties facebookResource() {
        return new ResourceServerProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean oauth2ClientFilterRegistration(
            OAuth2ClientContextFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        registration.setFilter(filter);
        registration.setOrder(-100);
        return registration;
    }

}
```

And it works. I can login and can get user info as described in tutorial. But I don't know how can I find the moment just after login and before redirect to main page for storing user details in database if user does not exist and verify his roles if exists.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Yo can make this class for storing user details in database after login. **successfulAuthentication** is executed after login.

```
class OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingAndSavingFilter extends OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    public OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingAndSavingFilter(String defaultFilterProcessesUrl) {
        super(defaultFilterProcessesUrl);
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
        super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, chain, authResult);

        SecurityContext context =  SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    }
}
```

After you must modifier OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter by OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingAndSavingFilter

```
private Filter ssoFilter() {
        OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingAndSavingFilter facebookFilter = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingAndSavingFilter("/login/facebook");
        OAuth2RestTemplate facebookTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(facebook(), oauth2ClientContext);
        facebookFilter.setRestTemplate(facebookTemplate);
        facebookFilter.setTokenServices(new UserInfoTokenServices(facebookResource().getUserInfoUri(), facebook().getClientId()));
        return facebookFilter;
    }
```